# Fuzzy match portions of an image

Tags: c#, image-processing, comparison, audio

I need to determine the existance of a smaller image inside a larger image.

The match must be fuzzy and preferrably I should know how well it matched (%), but I can calculate the accuracy my self after the match is done if required.

My goal is to match a FFT (Fast Fourier Transfrom) spectrogram (visualization of frequencies in music) with the original music track. The small image I'm matching with is only a subset (both in time and frequency range) of the original track (like a cutout of the image below).

Where should I start? Are the same algorithms used for object recognition suitable for this task?

I am primarily looking for C#/.Net libraries/samples, but also information on implementations and problems/pitfalls.

I am considering using artificual neural networks for training the recognition. Any thoughts?

Example of what the images I want to match may look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that treating this problem as an image recognition problem is ignoring the underlying structure of the problem.   Specifically you may want to look at how [Shazam](http://www.shazam.com/) addresses the problem.  This question on Quora has a couple of interesting links:

http://www.quora.com/How-does-Shazam-work

First, [an academic paper](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf) describing the algorithm.  You will notice that they also start with a spectrogram, but from there pick a small number of landmarks using an algorithm tailored to the problem.  They then essentially use that as a fingerprint id into a database.

Second, [an article on Slate](http://www.slate.com/id/2232914/) that is understandably at a higher level, but may still be helpful.

Comment: I ended up implementing this myself and I'm using some of the same techniques as Shazam. If I had seen this before it could had eased the process a lot (by not having to go through it;)). I'm considering making a blog article describing my approach, I'm fairly sure it won't break any Shazam patents.

Answer (score 0):

An Image Correlation *may* work. Depends on the differences between you full image and the partial one.

Example in Mathematica:

[image]

If you post a complete example of a full and partial images, perhaps we can work out more.

Other alternatives also exist: Comparing the FFTs and doing Wavelet Analysis, to name just two more.